# Custom android authenticator using Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, authentication

I would like to write a custom authenticator for Android. I found this nice tutorial to do it, but instead of using Parse as authentication server, I want to use Google App Engine:

http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

The problem is that I couldn’t find the way to do it. Do you know if that is possible?

All I can find is how to implement authentication using a Google account, but I’d rather prefer to allow users to use any email account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of choices, the first ones that come to mind:

1. You can use 3rd party OAuth providers which not all email providers are.
2. Implemment and use your own [Authenticator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Authenticator).
3. **(Recommended)** Since you are not accessing user data through OAuth just implement a standard user/password authentication method using endpoints and secure the API using your android's app SHA fingersprint, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth)